# Cloudera manager installation failed on ubuntu 12.0.4LTS

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera

I tried installing the latest cloudera manager on ubuntu and when i install the cluser on psuedo distributed mode I get the below error and can someone advise me what to do 
I did already try the following
a)disable the iptables 
b)changed my etc hosts to have following entries
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost

Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.

```
Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are free on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added (some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare hostname information on the Cloudera Manager and hosts also.

For example:

In Cloudera Manager:

```
10.1.3.11   hadoop-host1.localdomain hadoop-host1
10.1.3.12   hadoop-host2.localdomain hadoop-host2
...
```

In each hosts:

```
10.1.3.10   cloudera-manager.localdomain cloudera-manager
```

Put it simply, I used same list of hostnames for CM and all hosts.

Comment: I am installing cloudera manager on single host {one node cluster} and in cloudera manager i just specified as localhost and 127.0.0.1 .Is there anything else i need to specify?

Comment: I haven't tried to install Cloudera on single host, but in theory it should work. Try to restart cloudera-scm-agent after you update the /etc/hosts file.